# PHP/SQL - Uploading CSV to database - Different sheets daily/Multiple Tables

Tags: php, sql, csv, dump

I asked a question yesterday that was unclear and I've now expanded it slightly. In short, this current project calls for a simple web interface where the user can upload a csv file (this web page is created already). I've modified my PHP for a test file but my situation calls for something different. Every day, the user will upload 1 to 5 different CSV reports. These reports have about 110 fields/columns, though not all fields will be filled in every report. I've created a database with 5 tables, each table covering different fields out of the 110. For instance, one table holds info on the water meters (25 fields) and another table holds info for the tests done on the meters (45 fields). I'm having a hard time finding a way to take the CSV, once uploaded, and split the data into the different tables. I've heard of putting the whole CSV into one table and splitting from there with INSERT statements but I have questions with that:

1. Is there a way to put a CSV with 110 fields into one table without having fields created? Or would I have to create 110 fields in MYSQL workbench and then create a variable for each in PHP?
2. If not, would I be able to declare variables from the table dump so that the right data then goes into its correct table?

I'm not as familiar with CSVs in terms of uploading like this, usually just pulling a csv from a folder with a known file name, so that's where my confusion is coming from. Here is the PHP i've used as a simple test with only 10 columns. This was done to make sure the CSV upload works, which it does.

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "uwstest";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$c = 0;
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
 $one = $filesop[0];
 $two = $filesop[1];
 $three = $filesop[2];
 $four = $filesop[3];
 $five = $filesop[4];
 $six = $filesop[5];
 $seven = $filesop[6];
 $eight = $filesop[7];
 $nine = $filesop[8];
 $ten = $filesop[9];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO staging (One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven,    Eight, Nine, Ten) VALUES ('$one','$two', '$three','$four','$five','$six','$seven','$eight','$nine','$ten')";
 }

 if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "You database has imported successfully";
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
 }
 }
 }?>
```

Comment: Your code already selects specific columns only and inserts them into a table. Where is the problem in repeating that same step, but with different columns and a different INSERT statement …?

Comment: That's what I'm curious about. The above code works, as I can see the contents of the test csv in my database staging table. I'm just wondering if I would just need to do that for the actual CSV (110 columns) or if there was a better way. I've never worked with more than 10-20 columns on a CSV. I didn't know if I could just establish a variable for all 110 columns and then Create 5 insert statements for each table. Sorry if that seems weird, I'm still getting used to PHP on a larger scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on CSV size, you might want to consider using MySQL's native CSV import function since it runs 10x-100x times faster.

If you do insist on importing row by row, then you can do something like this with PDO (or adapt it to mysqli).

If you want to match columns, then ,either store your csv as associative array, or parse first row and store it in in array like $cols.

in this case, $results is an associative array that stores a row of csv with column_name=>column_value

```
$cols=implode(',',array_keys($result));
  $vals=':'.str_replace(",",",:",$cols);
  $inserter = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `mydb`.`mytable`($cols) VALUES($vals);");

   foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
   $result[':' . $k] = utf8_encode($v);
   if(is_null($v))
      $result[':' . $k] = null;
      unset($result[$k]);
    }
    $inserter->execute($result);
```

hope this helps.
I suggest going with PDO just to avoid all kinds of weirdness that you may encounter in CSV's data.

This is how I would create columns/vals.

```
$is_first=true;
$cols='';
$vals='';
$cols_array=array();
while (($csv = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
if($is_first)
{
$cols_array=$csv;
$cols=implode(',',$csv);
$is_first=false;
$vals=':'.str_replace(",",",:",$cols);
continue;
}

foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
   $result[':' . $cols_array[$k]] = utf8_encode($v);
   if(is_null($v))
      $result[':' . $cols_array[$k]] = null;
      unset($result[$k]);
    }
    $inserter->execute($result);
}
```

here is the code that I use for CSV imports.

```
        $file='data/data.csv';
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $path=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
        $full_path=$path."/../../$file";
        $cnt = 0;
        $is_first = true;
        $headers=array();
        $bind=array();
        $csv = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",");
        $headers=$csv;
        $alt_query='LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \''.$full_path.'\' INTO TABLE mytable 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
                ENCLOSED BY \'\"\'
                LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (' . implode(',',$headers).')';

echo exec("mysql -e \"USE mydb;$alt_query;\"",$output,$code);
```

Comment: So If I do this with PDO, since the CSV will always have the same columns, I can store everything row by row and associate each CSV column with the correct column name in each table?

Comment: yes. Just modify your code to fit your needs. My code is designed to import csvs that have partial data, or always changing data into one huge table. I removed code that creates new columns that dont exist since you dont need it.

Comment: I see. I'm trying with that code now, and I've modified some but no luck yet. How exactly would that factor in to my existing code correctly? Ive taken all of my code out of the while loop and replaced with your idea, modifying for my own purposes, but no luck.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code? and include errors/notices that might be showing up

Comment: I can shortly, I'm just using a variation of what you have with my own db and table, but I think my issue is creating the $result array. Also it's telling me that the PDO variable is unknown so I'm looking into how I need to implement that

Comment: Adding actual code that I am using for CSV imports.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relation between the tables and the CSV is arbitrary but uniform for now on you just need to establish that correspondence array index -> table column once.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you mean? The CSV will always be the same in terms of header/column name and order, and my 5 static tables have similar names for each column so the relationship between the tables and CSV should never change. Just a matter of whether or not certain fields are filled or empty.

Comment: Then if your concern was to automate somehow the process, i don't see any more option than mapping the array of the csv import to the table columns.